# SharePoint My Links Migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

My company is migrating from SharePoint 2010 and many of our users have extensive "My Links".  Since the "My Links" functionality is not in SharePoint Online, how do we provide this?

Is there a third party web part?
Is there a way to do this with custom code/extensions/pages, etc?

I know that in SharePoint 2010 I can go to "http://siteurl/_layouts/MyQuickLinks.aspx" to see my lists, but no easy way to download all of the data and especially for all the users.

Ideally we find a way to export each user's links and provide them in a similar link in SharePoint Online.
At a minimum, need to capture everyone's links and make them available in some format in SharePoint Online once we turn off SharePoint 2010.

Any ideas/Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint online there is a similar web part of my link is **Quick link** web part - you can try that - this is out of the box quick link web part.

**Refer to the below MSDN article how quick links web part works:**

[Use the Quick Links web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82)

**OR**

You can use the below Javascript code:

```
function quickLinksViewModel() {  
    var self = this;  
    self.myQuickLinks = ko.observableArray();  
    self.getMyQuickLinks = function(loginName) {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx/GetUserLinks",  
            method: "POST",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },  
            data: "{accountName:'" + loginName + "'}",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(data) {  
                self.myQuickLinks(data.d);  
            },  
            error: function(jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {  
                console.log(jqxr.responseText);  
            }  
        });  
    };  
    $.ajax({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentUser",  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            self.getMyQuickLinks(data.d.LoginName);  
        },  
        error: function(data) {  
            alert(data.error);  
        }  
    });  
}  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    ko.applyBindings(new quickLinksViewModel(), document.getElementById("divMyLinks"));  
});
```

**HTML code for displaying the quick links:**

```
<div id="divMyLinks" class="panel panel-default">  
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->  
    <div class="panel-heading" style="color: #ac1a2f;"><span class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--link"></span> My Links</div>  
    <div class="panel-body">  
        <div data-bind="foreach: myQuickLinks"> <span class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--link" style="color: #ac1a2f;"></span> <a data-bind="attr:{href: Url}" target="_blank"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></a></div> <span>This space shows your personal quick links. Use "Manage Links" to create your quick links. </span> <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" style="border-color:#ac1a2f;color:#ac1a2f" href="https://{tenantname}-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MyQuickLinks.aspx">Manage Links</a></div>  
</div>
```

**Description about the above code:**

If you see the code, we get the current user by using the REST API {sitecollectionurl]/_api/web/currentUser.

There are multiple ways to get user information in SharePoint Online, but not all of them give the user quick links (my links). We tried using REST API for User Information List which does not have quick links information. Then we tried using SP.UserProfiles.js to get all user properties from User Profile service and this gives the property “QuickLinks” and it is always empty.

So, the only working option was to use the old web service UserProfileService.asmx. If you check the URL {sitecollectionurl}/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx in Chrome, this will show you all the available methods under this web service and what we need is “**GetUserLinks**”

[image: Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online]

As you can see in the JavaScript code, the only parameter it needs is User Account name as input and the output is all links (Name, URL, Group) that user has saved as their favorites. The UI would look like –

[image: Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online2]

Now, users can save their favorite links in SharePoint My Site and see them and manage them from the Intranet home page.

Source:

[SharePoint My Site - My Links](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-my-site-my-links)

Also, if you have any third-party tools like **ShareGate** you can migrate the "my links" to SharePoint online.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response.  I do have ShareGate now, how would I migrate "my links" to SharePoint online?  

I have googled this and it still seems elusive.